# Are there default serializer implementations for common Java classes?

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.serialization

I'm trying out `kotlinx.serializaion`, and finding the lack of default support for common types a bit off-putting. Take for example `java.util.UUID`; even applying `@ContextualSerialization`, I get an error that the compiler can't locate an argument-less serializer for this type. Am I correct in assuming the recommended solution is to implement a custom serializer for UUID? Is there no way (or plan) to provide default serializers for common types as a quality-of-life feature?

Comment: i just asked myself the same question. I'm not sure if I understood it correctly, but maybe the commonplace option is not to use java citizens like `java.util.UUID` but kotlin-native citizens, such as `https://github.com/hfhbd/kotlinx-uuid`.